# 'Newest badge' links to wrong post

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page

On my [profile page](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/116151/glorfindel), my newest badge was shown: [Cleanup](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/4/cleanup?userid=116151). However, it linked to the [wrong question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6/116151); I actually earned it for rolling back the vandalism in  [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/379771/116151). The link on the badge page itself *is* correct. The wrong question has a very low post ID (6) which I think is not a coincidence.

Right now, it can't be verified anymore, because my newest badge is now Quorum, which – oh, the irony – I earned with this post.

[image: profile page with wrong link]

[image: badge page with correct link]

Comment: It seems a question better suited to meta than here. Have you searched n meta to see if other users have had something similar happened to them?

Comment: I'm pretty much amazed the badge has only been awarded 381 times, which suggests less than 400 users have used or ever use  the rollback function.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I assume you mean Meta Stack Exchange as opposed to Meta.EL&U? Technically speaking TPTB have said users can raise bugs, support, and technical issues on any Meta, so it's ok to have here. That said, I agree it would get more exposure and faster feedback on MSE than in our quiet little corner of the woods here.

Comment: @DanBron yes, I meant [SE meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), I know Glorfindel has posted there, so I'm a bit surprised he didn't think of going there first.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Wow, not only has he posted there, he's posted there *a lot*. I rarely have things I need to post on MSE! I was kinda proud of myself yesterday for posting something which got a handful of upvotes.... But since he has like ~11K there (!), he clearly knows the ropes and maybe deliberately chose to post here instead, based on some logic clear to him but less clear to me as a MSE newb? Anyway, we will see what he says when he comes back.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5Dbadge+awarded++wrong+question+  The results from this search suggests that this bug has not been reported before.

Comment: Yes, I could've posted it on Meta Stack Exchange. I generally post site-specific bugs, and bugs I can't reproduce on other sites on the child metas ([1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5293/11110), [2](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1572/4816), [3](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3348/18673), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340503/4751173)) and [networkwide bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288524/295232) on Meta SE. This is my way of adhering to MSE's scope: *Ask questions about issues that affect **all** Stack Exchange sites*.

Comment: The question which you posted on ELL meta was answered by Shog, who's really a regular on SE meta. I think tags (SO)  is something that is site specific, but icons, misaligned arrows, and this anomaly strike me as something that would interest more the developers over at SE than the mods, or a mere mortal user on EL&U. And the fact nobody responded  on Economics, and Puzzling seems to confirm my idea.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Posts tagged _feature-request, bug, support_, etc. from **all** SE sites reach TPTB in the same place. Only difference is, the normal users who respond to a meta post varies depending on the community.